# Query is always returning 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

The query is always returning 1 and not the `id` I need. I want the `id` of 'intervaloshorarios' table which has its own 'cita'. For example, (8:00 am to 9:00 am) for the date: 27/08/1988. I need (8:00 am to 9:00) id. I am returning the query using print_r($expression). How can I get the `id` that I need?

**Database**

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsiFW.png)

**Model function**

```
public function get_idintervalo($idCitas) {

     $query = $this->db->query('SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario FROM intervaloshorarios INNER JOIN citas '
             . 'ON intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario '
             . 'WHERE citas.idCitas = ' . $idCitas . ';');


        return print_r($query);
    }
```

**Controller(trying to get id into hidden field)**

```
 $query = $this->Intervalos_Model->get_idintervalo($idCitas);

  $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $query);
```

**Error (Sihas answer)**

[image: Localhost say: error while adding]

**Print_r($query)(Sihas answer
)**

1CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 1 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 1 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.1.21-MariaDB [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => Uptime: 1043645 Threads: 1 Questions: 58810 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 257 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 203 Queries per second avg: 0.056 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 3645 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )

Comment: if you want to fetch records from the table then you have to write like this: `$query = $this->db->query("Your select query")->row_array();` for one record OR `$query = $this->db->query("Your select query")->result_array();`  for multiple records.

Comment: Thanks @Nidhi but i have tried that too and it's not working...

Comment: Write `echo $this->db->last_query()` before return statement and execute that query in mysql and check results return or not.

Comment: I have solved this question with another question. Thanks anyway, I will answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting the value of the single field output using the codeigniter active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954107/getting-the-value-of-the-single-field-output-using-the-codeigniter-active-record)

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to look up some of the manual pages for these functions

[`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) outputs the variable (it echoes it) and returns `TRUE`, so returning in this manner will always return true (which could be interpreted as '1' if you for instance print that result). So return your result by actually returning it, not by echoeing it to the output!

Then you should look at your `query`. You are not saying what you use, but assuming you use PDO, look at the [manual of pdo's query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

> Return Values
>   PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

You will not get your result, you'll get a `PDOStatement`. You *can* itterate over this statement if you like, but it is not a string in itself. What you could do, for instance, is something like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

I have taken this from the following page: [phpdelusions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query), please take a look (not affiliated, just a random google hit :)  )

edit: you seem to be using `mysqli`. The same thing sort-of applies: check out the manual!

These 2 links should get you started
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
and
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php .

You could, for instance, do this:

```
 $result = $this->db->query($q);
 $array = $result->fetch_assoc();
 //now $array is an array with your results. var_dump it to inspect
```

Comment: Thank you! i am new with php and mysql and you're helping a lot! I have modified the function and it is throwing error: Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::fetch().

`public function get_idintervalo($idCitas) {
        
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT ... INNER JOIN citas ....'
    
                . 'WHERE ...);

        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
            
            echo $row['intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario'] . "\n";
        }

      }`

Comment: This will turn into a big question - answer - question - answer thread, and that is a bad format for this site. You should train yourself a bit in finding out things using the manual (no offence meant, but it will really help). In this case the issue is you are not using `PDO`, but you seem to be using `mysqli`. I will add a quick example for you.

Comment: Thank you! i will try that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public function get_idintervalo($idCitas)
{
    $this->db->select('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');
    $this->db->from('intervaloshorarios');
    $this->db->join('citas','intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario');
    $this->db->where('citas.idCitas',$idCitas);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result =  $query->row('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');

    echo $result; exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! it is throwing add error, so i can't add anything. I don't understand why...

Comment: Ok i will add the error message above. It is in Spanish but it's throwing: 'Localhost say: Error occurred while adding'

Comment: Are you getting any value in the hidden field `idIntervaloHorario` ?

Comment: I have done print_r($query) to see what is happening, I think it is gettin 1 again. I will add the print above.

Comment: you please don't print `$query`. Check the updated answer to see the value in the query.

Comment: instead of `$query->row('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');` try `$query->result('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');` also.

Comment: How can I do that? i am using your  `echo $query; exit();`  but nothing is shown, i'm sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: why you echo `$query` ? Please echo `$result`

Comment: `$query->result('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');` is throwing Message: Class 'intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario' not found and `echo $result; exit();` doesn't show anything...

Comment: Are you sure about the class definition and all while `extends`?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, with row it doesn't show class error but with result. What do you mean with while extends? class definition is correct.

Comment: with `row` are getting any value in `$result`?

Comment: I have checked all and everything is right, with the code above i click on the controller and nothing is showing (blank page), but if I use `return $query->result('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');` it's throwing class error

Comment: add `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select(); exit();` before this `$query = $this->db->get();` line and run the query in your database to make sure the query is correct.

Comment: Ok! this query is shown now: `SELECT `intervaloshorarios`.`idIntervaloHorario` FROM `intervaloshorarios` JOIN `citas` ON `intervaloshorarios`.`idIntervaloHorario` = `citas`.`idIntervaloHorario` WHERE `citas`.`idCitas` = '2'`

Comment: Did you run that query in your database and see the result?

Comment: Yes, I have tried too and it throws the expected result, so I don't know why it's not working on model and controller.

Comment: In the above code can change that `$query->row('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');` to `$query->result_array('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario');` and use `print_r($result);` instead of `echo $result`

Comment: I tried that before and throws next error: `Severity: Error

Message: Class 'intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario' not found`

Answer (score -1):

You just create alias of table and use Mysql In for multiple Id and pass array of Id

```
public function get_idintervalo($idCitas = array) 
{
    $query = SELECT in.idIntervaloHorario FROM intervaloshorarios in INNER JOIN citas ct ON in.idIntervaloHorario = ct.idIntervaloHorario WHERE citas.idCitas IN ( $idCitas );

$result = $this->db->query($query);
}
```

Comment: I have done this query now and it is returning array to string conversion:

`get_idintervalo($idCitas = array())`
`$query = "SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario FROM intervaloshorarios INNER JOIN citas "
                . "ON intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario "
                . "WHERE citas.idCitas IN  (' " . $idCitas . " ') ";
`
`$result = $this->db->query($query);
     return $result->result();`

Comment: Please refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565118/notice-array-to-string-conversion-in-php